# Using console to /setblock in a world other than "world"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

Is it possible to use the console to perform the command /setblock in a world other than the default "world"?

Using Minecraft Bukkit

Comment: What do you mean by the term "deafult world"?

Comment: @technikfe I suppose he means the overworld.

Comment: well, could mean the overworld or could mean other worlds that are saved on the server/pc. or might be using a multi-world plugin and wants to do stuff in another world than the main one.

Comment: >or might be using a multi-world plugin and wants to do stuff in another world than the main one.

Comment: for some reason I can't edit my comment, meant to say "this" in addition to it

Comment: so I'm assuming you're using bukkit? you should tag your question with `minecraft-bukkit` and/or `minecraft-server` then. :)
It would also be useful to include some form of information in the text of your question to make clear what exactely your setup is (e.g. bukkit/spigot, multi-world plugin, etc.) so you can get help with the problem you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No." Setblock's command usage:

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> <block> [dataValue|state] [oldBlockHandling] [dataTag]
```

does not provide a means for specifying a world. When used from the console changes will be applied to the default world (overworld). To make changes in other worlds such as The Nether or The End, the command must be executed in-game. A more detailed description of the command can be found in [How to Use the SetBlock Command in Minecraft](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/setblock_command.php).

Comment: Are there any possible alternatives that would allow this? Surely someone's gotta have made a plugin or something to fix this...?

Comment: Someone, somewhere has probably written a plugin to do exactly that; though, I find myself at a loss trying to think of a case for setting blocks from the console. I’d think it to be quite cumbersome for more than a few blocks without any visual feedback. If you can explain what it is that you are trying accomplish via `/setblock` from the console, I might be able to offer some better suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following:

```
/execute in minecraft:the_nether run setblock <x> <y> <z> <block> replace
```